# c++ SDL2 - ld||cannot find -lmingw32|

Tags: c++, sdl

I was creating program on windows with SDL2 and the program worked fine, but when I changed my os to linux mint (and install code::blocks, gcc, g++, SDL2), I run into troubles with compiling my code.

I have one error:

```
 - ld||cannot find -lmingw32|
```

I guess that I don't have mingw32 library, where can I get it? Or is the problem diferent?

BTW: I also tryed to google it.

Thank for response.

Comment: ***I don't have mingw32 library, where can I get it?*** You don't want it. Correct your makefile  / project file not to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read the manual](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation).

On linux you don't need `-lmingw32`. Instead, use

```
`sdl2-config --libs`
```

to get the list of all needed linker flags.

Example usage:

```
gcc -o myprogram myprogram.o `sdl2-config --libs`
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by removing linker on mingw32 and lib rotozoom.h.